# Why is Binding.CloseTimeout value ignored?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

Sessionful client has `Binding.CloseTimeout` set to 20 seconds:

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:00:20" ...
```

a) If service isn't running at the time client calls `proxy.Close`, then client should wait for 20 seconds ( due to `CloseTimeout` being set to 20 seconds )  before throwing an exception, but instead exception is thrown almost immediately:

*»The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:20'.«*

Why is `CloseTimeout` value ignored by client?

thank you

Comment: What are the other timeout settings for this service?

Comment: did you set the close timeout on your service config too? They must be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the client and server are people, and they have a meeting at noon.

The client shows up promptly at noon.  If the server isn't there then the client leaves immediately, saying "Screw it!" (throwing an exception).

If the server **is** there, they commence negotiations (setting up a connection).  If the meeting lasts less than `CloseTimeout` it's because they've come to an agreement (the connection has been set up).  If they run out of time for the meeting, they abandon their negotiations (the connection attempt times out).

Lest you think I'm making this up, it's confirmed by the answer to [this question over on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ca645b0c-cb10-4617-988f-cdb267dc8c94/):

> EncpointNotFoundException [sic] usually occurs if the service cannot be found on the specified address. This exception will be thrown immediately. But if the service is found, yet the sessionful channel cannot be established within 20 seconds, you'll encounter the timeout error.